# Run only one Python app with a GUI on an embedded computer: is a X server and a window manager really required?

Tags: python, embedded, wxpython, embedded-linux, kiosk-mode

I need to boot as fast as possible an embedded Linux computer (let's say < 5 seconds), and start **a unique Python application** (no other application will be run by the final user on this machine). The goal is something along the lines of my previous open-source project [SamplerBox](https://www.samplerbox.org).

The Python app has a GUI using wxPython (i.e. [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/)).

Do I need a X server for this? Or could Python directly start in graphical mode, without the need of an X server?

Also, do I need a window manager, or, since *only one* application will use the screen, no window manager is needed?

This seems possible, [as depicted here](https://embexus.com/2017/05/16/embedded-linux-fast-boot-techniques/) (impressive boot in 1 second from POWER BUTTON press to the GUI app!) but I wonder if it really needs to start a X server and a window manager.

Comment: You need to look up what backends are supported by wxWidgets, perhaps SDL. Anyway, this is not a Python question, but a wxWidgets question.

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer if you ask on SuperUser.

Comment: If you use wxWidgets you have to run X11 and the underlying graphics backend, no matter how many applications you intend to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a X server to run the application, but you can do it without a window manager if  that's the only application that will be running.

Just install the `xorg-xinit` package and create a `.xinitrc` file in the home directory like this:

```
exec mycommand
```

then run `startx`.

Comment: Thank you @DanielGomez. Should the last line be something like `exec python /home/me/myscript.py`? Then, where do I have to set up `startx`? (in which config file) Side-remark: which distro would you recommend to start this as fast as possible? (Not a distro in which we to have to build from source ;))

Comment: Yes, just create the `.xinitrc` file with `exec python /home/me/myscript.py` , after that startx should work (startx is just a frontend to xinit iirc). I can advice on a debian minimal install(with no wm) and then just installing xorg and xorg-xinit and whatever packages you need for python. Arch Linux is also a good option, and ubuntu minimal too.

Answer (score 1):

A Graphical display server like Xorg would be required to run your GUI app. But a window manager is not required as you can start your GUI app directly from X.